# Signed applet gives unsigned applet in jre 6 and 7 but works fine in jre 8

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet which is build in jdk6 it was signed and running fine now my certificate is expired and I am re-signing the applet by extracting old applet and removing the RSA files and entries in manifest file and re-archiving it. I have signed my applet with new certificate. in jre8 Applet show that its signed and its working fine on browser.

In jre6 and 7 it shows unsigned applet and its not working there.

I have tried to run following command

```
jarsigner -verify SecugenApplet.jar
```

which returns signed jar in jre8 and unsigned jar in jre6